# pandas.to_parquet pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Could not convert Timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I have a huge multiindex dataframe in long format. There's only one "value" column. Some entries in "value" are of type `pd.Timedelta`.

I got an error when trying to save that dataframe as `parquet` file using `pd.to_parquet`:

`pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: ("Could not convert Timedelta('2903 days 00:00:00') with type Timedelta: tried to convert to double", 'Conversion failed for column value with type object')`

If I convert the particular value from the error message to `numpy`, I get the following:

`array([Timedelta('2903 days 00:00:00')], dtype=object)`

I set up a toy example to check if it is possible at all to convert `pd.Timedelta` to `parquet`. The following code works just fine:

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [("A", "x"), ("A", "y"), ("B", "x"), ("B", "y")],
    names=["idx1", "idx2"])
data = {"value": [
    pd.Timedelta(days=10),
    2.5,
    pd.Timedelta(days=20),
    5
]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=idx)
df.to_parquet("test.parquet")

x = pd.read_parquet("test.parquet")
```

A simple `df.iloc[0, :].to_numpy()` delivers the exact same type as in my real dataframe: `array([Timedelta('10 days 00:00:00')], dtype=object)`.

I am wondering what might be the difference of my original dataframe compared to my toy example?

Comment: The "value" column of your data frame has got mixed data type (floats and Timedelta). Pyarrow and parquet won't support it. I think you need to unpivot the table to that the floats are in one column and the timedelta in another column.

Comment: That's what I thought, too. However, my toy example has also mixed data types, and this one is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Your toy example shoves the problem under the rug. `x` doesn't look like `df` (the floats have been converted to duration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your error `'Conversion failed for column value with type object'`, indicates that your column is a mixture between floats and time delta, as you expected.

The problem comes from the fact that pyarrow when you have a big dataframe infers, the types from the first rows of the pandas dataframe. Most probably in your case they are all floats. This code (the same example you have with a small modification) will reproduce your error:

```py
import pandas as pd

float_vals = [2.5 for i in range(10000)]
float_index_val = [("float", i) for i in range(10000)]
float_vals.extend([("A", "x"), ("A", "y"), ("B", "x"), ("B", "y")])
float_vals.extend([
    pd.Timedelta(days=2903),
    2.5,
    pd.Timedelta(days=20),
    5
])

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    float_vals,
    names=["idx1", "idx2"])
data = {"value": float_vals}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=idx)
df.to_parquet("test.parquet")

x = pd.read_parquet("test.parquet")
```

The problem here is that a column in parquet cannot have multiple types. In your example if you load the saved parquet you will see that everything has been converted to timedelta. For example `x = pd.read_parquet("test.parquet")` follow by`x.iloc[1, :].to_numpy()` delivers this `array([2], dtype='timedelta64[us]')`

If the float values do not represent a delta time you should do as the comment suggest and unpivot the data. If the float values represent a deltatime, you can transform them before saving, or pass a schema when saving.

```py
df.value = pd.to_timedelta(df.value)
df.to_parquet("test.parquet")
```

or

```py
df.to_parquet("test.parquet", schema=pa.schema([("value", pa.duration("s"))]))
```

Comment: Your code example is throwing an error. Anyway, I got your point. Thanks for clarification. Rather than transforming the floats into Timedelta, I need to do it the other way round, in my specific case.

Comment: I know the code example pretends to explain why you got the error in the initial point and you basic example does not have any error. So basically is intended to  throw the error (as explained in the post).